# Find records without reciprocal record in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, no-duplicates

I have a table let's say it has Color in one field and Shape in the other but in no particular field order:

```
FIELD1   | FIELD2
---------|----------
Red      | Triangle
Red      | Square
Red      | Circle
Triangle | Red
Square   | Red
```

I am trying to find records that do NOT have a reciprocal record and create one. So in the above table there is no reciprocal for

```
Red | Circle
```

while there are for

```
Red | Triangle
Red | Square
```

Is there a query that will
a) Identify which records don't have reciprocals
2) Create those records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT a.FIELD2, a.FIELD1 FROM tbl a 
LEFT JOIN tbl b ON b.FIELD2=a.FIELD1 AND b.FIELD1=a.FIELD2
WHERE b.FIELD1 is NULL
```

See here for a working example: [SQLfiddle1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/471853/2)

The `SELECT` joins the table onto itself by looking for the reciprocal record. If that record is *not found* then that record of the original table is listed with the order of columns reversed.

To *create* the missing records simply use the output in an `INSERT` statement like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (FIELD1,FIELD2)
SELECT a.FIELD2, a.FIELD1 FROM tbl a 
LEFT JOIN tbl b ON b.FIELD2=a.FIELD1 AND b.FIELD1=a.FIELD2
WHERE b.FIELD1 is NULL
```

Demo of complete example [SQLfiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fbf7/1).

Comment: Thank you I am testing that now (mine is a large table) but this seems workable into an update query for sure. FYI my other idea as since in fact the two fields are 5 digit integers I thought of creating a 'Product' field by multiplying each A and B field (e.g. 92451 | 90451 creates a Product field of 8362285401) and then I can just count(*) where that is 1